# Delete lines in file if no text beneath

Tags: file, awk, sed, filter

I have the following file which consists of tests and what they failed for (if they failed):

```
[Initial]
[Connect]
[Check]
FAILED cable orientation
[Power]
[Test1]
FAILED speed test
FAILED continuity
[Test2]
[Test restart]
```

The file syntax is:

- Test names which are enclosed by square brackets e.g. [Connect]
- Fail status which always starts with uppercase e.g. FAILED speed test

I want to filter out only the failed tests (test names and failures). So in this example I would have the following output:

```
[Check]
FAILED cable orientation
[Test1]
FAILED speed test
FAILED continuity
```

I tried to do this using sed and awk but failed miserably.

Comment: `filter out` means `remove`. Is that what you really want? Restate the question as `I want to print the tests that failed` or `I want to print the tests that did not fail`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how long your test files are, you might want to use this:

```
    grep "FAILED" file.txt -B1
```

Running this on your given text file will yield:

```
    [Check]
    FAILED cable orientation
    --
    [Test1]
    FAILED speed test
    FAILED continuity
```

If you don't want the hyphens you can remove them by piping the `grep` into `sed '/--/d'` or you can try using the `--no-group-separator` option (I'm not sure if all versions of `grep` come with this option, so I would stick with `sed`).

So running `grep "FAILED" file.txt -B1 | sed '/--/d'` yields:

```
    [Check]
    FAILED cable orientation
    [Test1]
    FAILED speed test
    FAILED continuity
```

Comment: Is this an issue about my answer not working for you, or an issue with how `grep -B1` works?

Answer (score 0):

a lazy solution would be with the `tac` tool:

```
tac file|awk '/^FAILED/{f=1;print}/^\[/{if(f)print;f=0}' |tac
```

test:

```
kent$  cat f
[Initial]
[Connect]
[Check]
FAILED cable orientation
[Power]
[Test1]
FAILED speed test
FAILED continuity
[Test2]
[Test restart]

kent$  tac f|awk '/^FAILED/{f=1;print}/^\[/{if(f)print;f=0}' |tac
[Check]
FAILED cable orientation
[Test1]
FAILED speed test
FAILED continuity
```